# Is there a simple way to store bash variables via jq?

Tags: bash, jq

I am seeking an easy way to create persistent bash associative array (dictionary) storage without using `declare` and its options to manually read and write associative arrays externally.

'jq' and 'json' storage is certainly more capable than internal bash storage, but a simple answer for interfacing bash with 'jq' is eluding me in the huge mass of 'jq' information.

Can I use `jq` and `JSON` files to store/recall/delete persistent keyed string values in bash instead of using volatile bash associative arrays?

Note: Thank you for your comments and I believe I've worded my question better, but to add an example is not applicable to this question.

Comment: For future reference: Please provide an example of the operations you want to perform, along with example input and corresponding desired output. Also, please include examples of what you already did, this usually helps to avoid getting answers that you already know won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Read

Reading a value is easy enough via `--raw-output` which removes js quoting in the output and `// empty` which removes `null` (and `false`) output...

```
echo '{"Z":"zee","V":"vee"}' > d
V=$(jq --raw-output '.V // empty' d)
```

Use `--exit-status` if you want to distinguish between the empty string value and not found which js calls `null`...

```
echo '{"Z":"zee","V":"vee"}' > d
V=$(jq --exit-status --raw-output '.X' d)
```

Assigns `null` to `$V` and `1` to `$?` because key `X` was not found.

### Write

Passing a value via `--arg NAME VALUE` causes `jq` to accept `VALUE` as a command line argument and assign it's `JSON` string representation to `NAME` which can be referenced in the `jq` input as `$ARGS.named.NAME`...

```
echo '{"Z":"zee","V":"vee"}' > d
V=$'This\tis a fancy\nvalue containing "quotes" and more \\'
sponge d < <(jq --arg V "$V" '."V"=$ARGS.named.V' d)
```

Passing a value via `--rawfile NAME FILE` causes `jq` to accept the contents of `FILE` and assign it's `JSON` string representation to `NAME` which can be referenced in the `jq` input as `$NAME`...

```
echo '{"Z":"zee","V":"vee"}' > d
sponge d < <(jq --rawfile V <(printf 'This\tis a fancy\nvalue containing "quotes" and more \\') '."V"=$V' d)
```

### Delete

Deleting a value is easy...

```
sponge d < <(jq 'del(.V)' d)
```

### Comment

Examples here use the form `sponge FILE < <(jq ... FILE)` to emulate an inline replace of `FILE`. Any other method like `JSON=$(jq ...)` can be used, but `jq ... FILE | sponge FILE` causes `sponge` to empty `FILE` if an error occurs during `jq` (easily caused by malformed input or literal) which cannot be stopped by `set -e` and `set -o pipefail`. On the bright side, `sponge FILE < <(jq ... FILE)` halts execution of `sponge` if an error occurs during generation of its input leaving `FILE` intact.

Comment: It's a good answer, but your question is too vague. It would help future readers if you were to add an example of thing you want to do with bash and jq.